# Redirect all URLs Post WP

Tags: php, regex, wordpress

I changed the Permalink struct: `/%post_id%/%postname%-(. *)/` to redirect all my post URLs to the post's unique `post_id`. It worked.
For example: `/11/london-very nice` or `/11/london-very romantic` all point to posts with `post_id = 11`.
However, the URLs of the original post always have the character `(.*)` that is not good.
I appreciate any solution.

Comment: IMO, Using **[`/\/^%post_id%/%postname%-(.*)$/ig`](https://regex101.com/r/QGB5zi/7)** will works correctly, if not please provide some sample data that it doesn't work ;).

Comment: So sorry. It does not match the Permalink structure on WP.

Comment: Can you please add some samples of the Permalink structure on WP that does not match? ;).

Comment: So sorry. I'm trying it again. Hope to work

Comment: So sorry. Maybe you do not understand me. For example: I have the original post url "/11/london-examble-(.*)/".
Now I have 2 URLs: "/11/london-very nice" and "/ 11 / london-very romantic" all point to post_id = 11. When I add "(. *)" after "%postname%" means anything after "%postname%" it always causes the URL to point to "/%post_id%/%postname%". Now I do not want the "(. *)" character to appear on the URLs and it still works the same way.